# Posting a reply to a tweet using Zapier

Tags: zapier

I was wondering if there is a way to post a reply to a specific tweet using Zapier?  By the looks of it, the only way would be to use webhooks and post the json, but it just would be so much simpler if I could the built in twitter functionality of Zapier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible because it goes against Twitter's policies: https://zapier.com/help/twitter/#using-zapier-as-a-twitter-auto-responder

Comment: Yes and No.
It's true that you can't do it on Zapier, but it's false that Twitter doesn't allow it.
Twitter DOES allow it if the trigger tweet is directed to you.
So, if `@aaa` mention user `@bbb`, the user `@bbb` is able to create an automated reply to `@aaa`.

Comment: @BrodaNoel Do you have an update on this?  I'm trying to get Zapier to respond to a tweet that mentions my account, but I can't get the '@' symbol into the response.